# Passando valor de uma view para outra view - PHP

Tags: php, mvc, link, view

Galera, preciso passar um valor de uma View para outra View, no caso um ID. Por exemplo:

Na View principal eu tenho uma lista de vagas, quando eu clicar em uma das vagas carregará a segunda View onde será possível editar esta vaga. Minha duvida é como passar o valor do ID desta de uma forma correta, sem que o usuário possa modificar o valor no link inspecionando pelo navegador.

Comment: O ideal seria armazenar isso em $_SESSION. Você está usando algum framework?

Comment: Não, sem framework, somente o MVC @AndréRibeiro

Comment: `get_defined_vars()` dentro da estrutura da view retornaria todas as variáveis ali declaradas. Talvez, você poderia fazer algo com isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso não tem como, o que você pode fazer é criar um bloqueio antes de gerar o link.

Por exemplo, um hash que permita o acesso aquele id ou diretamente a vaga, e ao invés de passar o id para a url gerada você passa o hash.

A pagina que receber encontra o id da vaga atravéz do hash.

Url exemplo:

```
?vagahash=202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
```

Código exemplo:

```
// Recebe o hash enviado, neste caso por GET
$hash = $_GET['vaga'];

// Instancia o Dao para funcoes de busca no banco de dados relacionadas a vaga
$vagaDao = new VagaDao();

// Seleciona a vaga atravez do hash
$vaga = $vagaDao->selectByHash($hash);
```

Dessa forma com o hash gerado por você, fica difícil o usuário modificar com sucesso.

Espero te-lo ajudado.